# How to make the bar have the same color in the same group when plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure

[image]

In this figure, we have two groups of bars, A and B. How to make the bars in group A have the same color a, and bars in group B have the same color b. And how to produce the legend for these two groups.

Thanks.

code:

```
latency = [62.36 80 793.17 215.15 199.39 ; 
           43.21 50 221 206.90 10 ]; 
h = bar(latency, 1);
set(h, 'FaceColor',[64 224 208]./255,'LineWidth', 0.7)
set(gca,'linewidth',0.8,'Fontname', 'Arial', 'FontWeight', 'bold');
set(gca,'XLim',[0.5, size(latency,1)+0.5], ...
   'XTick',[0.69:0.155:1.4 1.70:0.155:2.3], ...
   'XTickLabel',{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'});
box on;
```

Comment: Start with reading [ask]. You'll learn there to **show your effort**. Showing us how to make a bar graph is a start, but did you e.g. read [the documentation on `bar()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html)? That quite clearly tells you what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two bar plots in one axes:

```
figure;
h1 = bar(1:5, latency(1,:));
hold on;
h2 = bar(7:11, latency(2,:));
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = [1:5, 7:11]
ax.XTickLabel={'A','B','C','D','E','A','B','C','D','E'}
```

You can use `h1` and `h2` to access and modify the `Bar` objects.

[image]